# Преобразовать строку в зависимости от ее признака в БД в простые типы данных C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Вытаскиваю с БД таблицу в которой есть |id|Code|Type|Value| в модель:

```
public record MyDto
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    public Code Code { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо по признаку |Type| вернуть из метода соответствующий тип данных лежащий в поле Value которая парситься всегда в строку, но ее содержимое может быть например "100" или "Привет Мир!". Я ничего лучшего пока не придумал, но очень сомнительный код:

```
 public async Task<object> GetDataByCodeAsync(Code code, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var result = await _repository.GetDataByCodeAsync(code, token);

        switch (result.Type)
        {
            case Type.String:
                return result.Value.ToString();
            case Type.Decimal:
                return Convert.ToDecimal(result.Value);
            case Type.Integer:
                return Convert.ToInt32(result.Value);
            case Type.Guid:
                return Guid.Parse(result.Value);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

Можно пока без проверок или `TryParse`, просто сугубо понимать, как реализовать в нормальном виде.

Comment: Зачем у метода `<T>`, если обобщение никак не используется?

Comment: Метод возвращает `object`. То есть значимые типы боксятся. В целом это выглядит сомнительно и неэффективно. Может, опишете задачу более крупно? Авось удастся найти решение лучше на более высоком уровне.

Comment: Замечание: в соответствии с Framework Design Guidelines параметр типа `CancellationToken` всегда должен задаваться как опциональный: `CancellationToken cancellationToken = default`. Он единственный, для которого сделано такое исключение.

Comment: Т это рудимент, метод раньше был обобщённым. Просто копипаста. Задача описана, больше и описать-тл в принципе мне нечего. Т.е по полученному признаку типу из бд сконвертировать в реальный (int, guid, string...).

Comment: `MyDto` для чего показана? В коде она никак не используется.

Comment: `MyDto` - это значение в `var result`. На нее мэпяться данные из запроса к БД.

Comment: `SettingType` != `Type`. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте код в вопросе, чтобы он был релевантным.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы метод `GetDataByCodeAsync` возвращал конкретный тип - `int`, `decimal` и т. п.? Это невозможно.

Comment: Если речь идет чисто про то, чтобы вернуть тип с нужным, сконвертированным значением, то для этого в C# есть `Convert.ChangeType(....)`, который отлично подходит под ваш код, ибо вы можете заменить весь `switch` на нечто такое `return Convert.ChangeType(result.Value, result.Type);`, но вот с `Task<object>`, тут уже сложнее, ибо он подразумевает то, что тип будет задан при вызове метода и тут наверно лучше вызывать `Convert.ChangeType` за пределами метода, там, где он нужен уже сконвертированный, либо Type передавать методу, тогда `result.Type` заменять на `typeof(T)`.

Comment: Что вы дальше собираетесь делать с полученным значением динамического типа? ИМХО, решить такую задачу на C# можно только с помощью `object` либо `dynamic`. И то, и то не очень хорошо

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - `Convert.ChangeType` не со всеми типами справится. Например, `Guid` он не сможет преобразовать из строки. Поэтому я его и не стал предлагать. К тому же, для его работы нужен конкретный тип или перечисление `TypeCode`, а у автора собственное перечисление.

Comment: Не давайте своим типам имена, совпадающие с системными. Я про `Type`. Это может доставить много неудобств. В частности, при переходе с .NET FW 4.0 на .NET FW 4.5 именно с `Type` народ огрёб кучу проблем... Лучше оставить имя `SettingType`.

Answer (score 5):

Можно применить паттерн-матчинг для лаконичности:

```
return result.Type switch
{
    SettingType.String => result.Value,
    SettingType.Decimal => decimal.Parse(result.Value),
    SettingType.Integer => int.Parse(result.Value),
    SettingType.Guid => Guid.Parse(result.Value),
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
};
```

---

Давайте разберёмся.
Ваш метод `GetDataByCodeAsync` возвращает какое-то значение. Что дальше с ним происходит? Очевидно, оно как-то обрабатывается. И, вероятно, обрабатывать нужно по разному в зависимости от типа.

Мне много раз попадались такие вопросы с конвертацией типа из строки и дальнейшим его использованием. На предложения показать проблему более широко практически всегда авторы упираются и хотят непременно чёрную магию: чтобы оно само как-то работало...

В тех задачах, что я видел, обычно код выглядит примерно так:

```
object value = GetDataByCode(...);
Process(value);
```

Внутри `Process` опять приходится определять, какой именно тип имеет параметр `value`: `if (value is int n) ...` и т. п. То есть от чего уходили, к тому и вернулись. Разница лишь в том, что теперь тип задан не строкой.

Предлагаю следующее.

```
public async Task ProcessDataByCodeAsync(Code code, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var result = await _repository.GetDataByCodeAsync(code, token);

    switch (result.Type)
    {
        case SettingType.String:
            Process(result.Value);
            break;
        case SettingType.Decimal:
            Process(decimal.Parse(result.Value));
            break;
        case SettingType.Integer:
            Process(int.Parse(result.Value));
            break;
        case SettingType.Guid:
            Process(Guid.Parse(result.Value));
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

И несколько перегрузок метода, принимающих нужный тип:

```
void Process(string value) { }
void Process(decimal value) { }
void Process(int value) { }
void Process(Guid value) { }
```

Таким образом наш метод выполняет диспетчеризацию в одном-единственном месте. А дальше мы без проблем работаем с конкретными типами.

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` для индексаторов же :) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception

Comment: Это конечно красиво, но суть вопроса, как сделать возвращаемое значение по типу.

Comment: @JDo  используйте `Task<dynamic>`, если хотите, чтобы метод мог менять тип возвращаемого значения в runtime, но работать будет медленно

Comment: @JDo - посмотрите обновление.