# C# Метод возвращающий разные типы данных

Tags: c#

Пример кода

```
    using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var res = GetInitialized();
        if(res is bool)
            Console.WriteLine("bool");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("string");
    }
    private static object GetInitialized(string res = null)
        {
            object result = true;
            if (res == null)
                result = false;
            else
                result = "Не пустой входной параметр";
            return result;
        }
}
```

Какими вариантами ещё можно возвращать разные типы данных?

Comment: Самое главное - зачем возвращать разные типы данных, и какая из этого польза? C# - строго типизированный язык, из этого надо пользу извлекать, а не бороться с этим.

Comment: @aepot делаю библиотеку которая возвращает string ответы, и например если ошибка произошла при работает с библиотекой, то я бы хотел возвращать boo со значением false

Comment: @aepot а в целом вы конечно правы и сказав про типизированность, пришло на решение, что я могу так же возвращать null в ответ если была ошибка

Comment: В таком случае делают класс, который содержит и то и то сразу, а в случае `false` уже тогда читают, например `class.ErrorMessage`.

Comment: А исключения тогда для чего созданы?

Comment: В этом случае класс об обработке ошибок или throw не нужен, так как от него пользы никакой нет, только лишний код в библиотеки и на стороне использования библиотеки, сделал просто возврат null.

Comment: Вспомнил как это зовется - OperationResult, например [вот](https://medium.com/@cummingsi1993/the-operation-result-pattern-a-simple-guide-fe10ff959080) или [вот](https://www.calabonga.net/blog/post/operationresult-kak-rezultat-operacii-zaprosa-na-backend) - суть та, которую вы хотите, только в обычном приложение так не всегда пишут, это больше Web практика.

Comment: _В этом случае класс об обработке ошибок_ - о чем? Давайте конкретный пример и конкретную проблему, а не абстракный разбор `object`'ов в вакууме.

Comment: 1) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1320281/373567 2) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277782/373567

Comment: Пишите такую библиотеку на javascript, PHP, Python

Comment: @aepot по 1 ссылке интересно было почитать, а вот по 2 вариант только для не асинхронных приложений или разбивкой на task и метод string, что не всегда удобно как по мне.

Comment: А про пример он и не нужен, цель получить ответ да или нет, в случае нет, возвращаем данных нет, а там можно писать в лог к примеру) Сделал просто возврат null в случае не полученных данных.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ интересно было почитать) Для сложной обработки данных такое явно пригодится

Comment: @Виктор Тема помечена тегом C# а не переходам на друге языки

Comment: Что потом будет делаться с возвращёнными данными? Это именно "данные", или объект, который сам будет выполнять какие-то действия? / В любом случае возвращаем некий общий тип. Сейчас это `object`. Может быть базовый класс или интерфейс. / https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1410895/184217 - вот пример обработки, в зависимости от типа. / Также смотрите паттерн Посетитель (Visitor) - применяется для мультидиспатча.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у меня возрашает bool и  string если true, то идет работа со строй, если false, значит ответ не корректный и в обработке не нуждается, по сути примитивная функция, цель вопроса, сравнить методы как лучше возрашать подобные данные, ответов в теме достаточно много собралось, все хороши для своих задач в зависимости от желаемого  результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это проблема XY. У вас, Иван, похоже проблема в чём-то другом. Вы подумали, что её можно решить, возвращая разные типы данных, но как это сделать - это тоже проблема.

Если просто нужно вернуть какие-то данные, то для этого есть либо параметры, передающиеся по ссылке (модификатор ref), либо выходные параметры (модификатор out). Смотрите документацию по применению.

Обычно метод возвращает результат операции. Если это какой-то проверочный метод, как, например, Parse/TryParse, то либо вызывается исключение (Parse), либо возвращается логическое значение (TryParse).

```
public static bool TryParse (string? s, out int result);
```

А вот само значение возвращается через аргумент result, который с модификатором out.

Ещё есть кортежи (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), которые позволяют возвращать несколько значений различных типов.

Возможно, нужно сделать так:

```
    private static bool GetInitialized(string res = null, out string status)
    {
        if (res == null)
        {
            status = "Пустой входной параметр";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Не пустой входной параметр";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: почитал все, вариант с кортежами, очень понравился, использование для моей задачи, лучше не не придумаешь) спасибо)